# How to limit the numbers in Django2.0 urls syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

```
path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
```

Here, How to limit year into 4 digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In django 2.0 [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) is introduced for regex.

you need to import it as:

```
from django.urls import re_path
```

and use as below:

```
re_path('articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/', views.year_archive),
```

and below statement is compatible with django 2.0 as well as previous version of django(>=1.8 as of my knowledge)

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
```

so regex is created for getting exactly 4 digits in keyword argument `year`